# Cake PHP Error: Make sure you have created index.ctp (???)

Tags: php, cakephp

I was just starting to learn cakephp today by going through a "blog tutorial". I created my **blog_controller.php** and then created a folder named **'blog'** with the **apps/views/** structure. The next step in the tutorial was to create the **index.ctp** file within the blog folder under views. In the tutorial it declares that all error messages should be gone. However, I still receive an error message:

> Error:  The view for
>   BlogController::index() was not found.
>
> Error:  Confirm you have created the
>   file:
>   /Users/trippstephens/Dropbox/cakephp-cakephp1x-348e5f0/app/views/blog/index.ctp

For the life of me, I can not figure out what I have done wrong. I am running cakephp under **MAMP** and it "installed" successfully. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "created a folder named 'blog' with the apps/views/ structure" part. Does the file `/Users/trippstephens/Dropbox/cakephp-cakephp1x-348e5f0/app/views/blog/index.ctp` actually exist?

Comment: To add on to Mike: if it exists, verify read permissions are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a couple of conventions issues going on here:

1. Your controller should be plural: `BlogsController` with file name `blogs_controller`.
2. Your views should exist in `app/views/blogs/` (note the plural)

Your model should be singular (`Blog`), but that may already be the case (you don't include any model info).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't really want a blog controller.  Instead, you have your blog *database* with a *posts* table that contains all the blog posts you have.  So, you would have `/app/controllers/posts_controller.php` and `/app/views/posts/index.ctp`.

Please refer to this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/23/File-and-Classname-Conventions for how CakePHP capitalizes and pluralizes your names.